# Understanding Tour Of Heroes catchError implementation

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to understand the implementation of **catchError** over an Http request in the Angular official tutorial (Tour Of Heroes).

The code of the http request is this:

```
this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
.pipe(catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', [])));
```

Inside the catchError, it passes the handleError function, which is implemented **like** this (summarized)

```
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    //Various operation with the error variable..

    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

Since I'm new to TypeScript, I've tried to read documentation about this kind of syntax (and I've read also other questions about this piece of code), but I didn't find a reply:
what does

```
return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
```

means? I don't understand how to read it: who valorize the error variable? How?

I read that catchError require a parameter that is a function with 2 parameters: err, which is the error, and caught, which is the source observable, but I don't see how error is valorized here. I supposed that in catchError I had to pass handleError(err, caught).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleError` isn't the function you pass to `catchError`, `handleError` is the function you call so that it can return a function that you can pass to `catchError`. That makes it a [*higher-order function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), making use of the fact that in Javascript and Typescript functions are first-class objects.

The returned function is an anonymous function in [arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), annotated with types. Without types, and with a better name, it may make more sense:

```js
private getErrorHandler<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error) => {
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

The types merely say that *the function returned by invoking `handleError`* is *a function that accepts an error and returns an Observable of type `T`*.

> I read that catchError require a parameter that is a function with 2 parameters: err, which is the error, and caught, which is the source observable

In Javascript, you can always *supply more arguments than the function is expecting* and the function will simply ignore the extras. The function that `handleError` returns presumably does not use the source Observable at all, so you can omit it in Javascript. Ostensibly Typescript [doesn't allow extra arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters), and catchError [definitely accepts a two-arg method](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError), but because of Javascript's flexibility it allows you to cast a one-arg method into a two-arg method and discard the second parameter (see ["Comparing two functions"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) in the Typescript Type Compatibility docs).

A different way of phrasing the same thing, using the `function` keyword instead:

```js
private createFunctionForCatchError<T>(operation, result) {
  return function(error, unusedSourceObservable) {
    // Discard error and return an Observable of the result.
    return observableOf(result);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification, coming from a backend background, sometimes it's difficult to think with a new logic such as passing and returning function as parameter, and even more with a shorter syntax. Thanks again!